# Write mathematical operators in typewriter font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, typewriter

I want to typeset unicode symbols like `≥ (U+2265)` and `∧ (U+2227)` in the typewriter / tt / monospaced / non-proportional font of my document. I don't care how I have to enter these symbols in my .tex files. Entering `≥` or using a commando like `\ge` is both fine as long as I can do so inside `\texttt` and `\begin{verbatim}`.

I know that I can enter unicode signs directly using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2265}{\ge}`. However, the command `\ge` can only be used in math mode which changes the font. Therefore `\texttt{$\ge$}` is not a solution. Also, I have to use `pdflatex` so XeTeX or LuaLaTeX are not an option for me.

Is there a way to output a `≥` in the current non-math font?

Comment: do you have a pdftex compatible monospace font that has these symbols?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure. I'm using `beramono`. At least the ttf/otf version ["bitstream vera sans mono" supports ≥](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/bitstream_vera_sans_mono/list.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cmtex10` font:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtex}{m}{n}{<-> cmtex10}{}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textttex}{\usefont{OT1}{cmtex}{m}{n}}

\newunicodechar{≤}{\ifmmode\le\else\textttex{\symbol{"1C}}\fi}
\newunicodechar{≥}{\ifmmode\ge\else\textttex{\symbol{"1D}}\fi}

\begin{document}

abc ≥ def ≤ uuu

\verb|abc ≥ def ≤ uuu|

$a≤b$ $a≥b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the font table, so you can use other characters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still try to figure out how to use other fonts with this approach, for instance `beramono`. As I'm a bit busy right now I'll come back to this question later.